# How to prevent service messages from being marked as SPAM?

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer, subscription

I am supporting a small stand-alone service for authors, who wish to share their texts with others, discuss them and so on.

As any service it requires sending lots of mails: activation (after join), confirmations and so on. I am using PHPMailer for that purpose.

**Question:** What additional steps should I take to prevent mails, sent by the service to be marked as SPAM? Should I adjust DNS settings somehow? Could I register my server with popular mail services somehow?

Any links as well as what comes from your experience are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**1. Mail header**

Use correct mail haders, when you send an mail.

**2. DNS Settings**

***>> DNS Part 1***

Be sure that you have configurated your Zonefile/DNS Server correctly. Create an TXT Record, a small range of providers check the SPF-Record (Replace the IP `255.255.255.255` with your's).

If your provider accept editing the complete Zonefile, add following line:

`@                    300 IN TXT     "v=spf1 ip4:255.255.255.255 ~all"`

Otherwise create an TXT Record with the content `v=spf1 ip4:255.255.255.255 ~all`

***>> DNS Part 2***

Add an reverse DNS (rDNS) entry. rDNS resolve your IP `255.255.255.255` to the right hostname (it's the contrary from domain resolving)

***>> DNS Part 3***

Check if you have set an MX record.

**3. Server Settings**

Be sure that your server is configured. Check if the correct hostname is configured!

**4. Testing**

Test your system with a lot of freemailer's like GMX, Google-Mail, Yahoo-Mail and other to check if the mail going to the spam folder.

Comment: Where should I create SPF TXT record, in registrar panel or on my webhosting?

Comment: I host my site on the server with other sites on it (also mine). How could it affect mail trustworthiness? (if IP resolves to ANOTHER host)

Comment: On your domain administration

Comment: its not an problem if you hosting other sites when you set an rDNS entry

Comment: @Adrian_Preuss But my reverse DNS entry could point to one domain only?

Comment: right. Enter here the hostname of your server or the mail-subdomain

Answer (score 0):

Good keywords to google for, if you are going to send any emails from your server:

- SPF (Sender Policy Framework);
- DKIM (DomainKeys Identified Mail);
- marketing/transactional emails;
- mail exchanger record (MX record)
- Postfix (mail transfer agent)

*One more note.* It's easier, cheaper and **much more reliable** to use one of the existing email delivery services (google SendGrid, Amazon SES) if you are small startup service.

Why? Just because emails work that way. Those services have quite a reputation and they do review your application before you can send any emails. So you are buying not only some technical tools, but also a share of their reputation, which is not that easy to earn from scratch.

If you design you mailing system right (always save everything you send out to database!), it would be easy to switch to any other solution in the future.